# How do I search by properties of entity which do not have @Column anotation in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

```
 /**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Order extends BaseEntity
{
// this is trait for @Id
use Identifier;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
protected $costPerUnit;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
protected $numberOfUnits;

// i want to search by this property
protected $totalCost;

public function getTotalCost()
{
 return $this->numberOfUnits * $this->costPerUnit;
}

}
```

I have an entity like this and I'd like to be able to do for example

```
$orderRepository->findOneByTotalCost('999')
$orderRepository->findBy(['totalCost' => '400']);
```

Is this possible in Doctrine2? Or would I go about it differently?

Comment: You must map this column, otherwise it will not be possible.
How are you doing the mapping?

Comment: @fkupper I have edited my question to better illustrate what I am trying to solve

Comment: Good, but again, there is not way to use virtual properties on DQL.
Not that I know at least.

Comment: How would I solve this then? I don't want to save $totalCost in database obviously, but I'd like to be able to search by it.

Comment: You should create a query that sums these values, more like a common sql query. I'll write an answer for that.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: It is possible I am trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist. Can you tell me how should I correctly search for all orders where total costs is above or below a certain number?

Comment: @user1848605: The easiest think I can think of (going on the code you've posted) is to store the amount of items,the total price, and a oneToOne relation to a product entity, which holds the price. Or just store the total, and the Nr. of items. You can compute the price per item by dividing the total by the number of units...

Comment: So the answer is denormalizing my database schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a method findOneByTotalCost on your entity repository, something like:

```
public function findOneByTotalCost ($queryParams){

    $query = 'select o
                from <yourEntity> o
               where o.numberOfUnits * o.costPerUnit = :myParam';


    $dql = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($query);
    $dql->setParameter('myParam', $queryParams);       

    return $dql ->execute();


}
```

Them, $orderRepository->findOneByTotalCost('999') should work.

Comment: Let's say I also need this information on the level of a single entity, for example $order123->getTotalCost(). Does this mean I have to write the same logic both on the entity and in my repository? That doesn't seem right

Comment: You can have both.
When you need this virtual information direct from the entity, use the method getTotalCost() and when you need to search, use the repository method findOneByTotalCost ()

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in my comments, it's likely you're wrestling with an issue that shouldn't have occurred in the first place. Still, having a `SUM` value mapped to a property *is* possible using doctrine, in a variety of ways: [Check the aggregate field docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html) to find out which would solve your problem best.

To my eyes, is that you're using entities as more than what they really are: Entities represent records in a database, Doctrine is a DBAL. Searching data using entities (or repositories) **is** querying the database. You could solve the problem by adding custom methods to your entity manager or a custom repository class that'll query all of the data required to compute the totalCost value for all entities, and return only those you need. Alternatively, use the connection from your DBAL to query for the id's you're after (for example), then use *those* values to get to the actual entities. Or, like I said before: use aggregate fields.

---

The problems you have with the `findOneByTotalCost` and `findBy` examples you show is that the first requires you to write a method *Called* `findOneByTotalCost` yourself. The problem with your use of `findBy` is simply that your argument is malformed: the array should be associative: use the mapped column names as keys, and the values are what you want to query for:

```
$repo->findBy(
    ['totalCost' => 400]
);
```

is what you're looking for, not `['totalCost', 400]`. As for the entity itself, you'll need to add an annotation:

Yes it is, judging by your use of `@ORM\Entity` annotations in the doc-blocks, this ought to do it:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $regioun = 'Spain';
```

The update the table, and you'll be able to:

```
$entities = $repo->findBy(
    ['region' => 'Spain']
);
```

Don't forget that this code represents a table in a DB: you can search on any of the fields, but use indexes, which you can do by adding annotations at the top of your class definition:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="tblname", indexes={
 *  @ORM\Index(name="region", columns={"region"})
 * })
 */
class Foo
{}
```

As ever: in DB's, indexes *matter*

Comment: I am specifically trying to avoid the Columnd annotation, because that means the value is persisted. I don't want to persist $totalCost, but I want to be able to search by it.

Comment: @user1848605: commented below your answer on that matter